# Generic field/method in non-generic class in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, generics, flutter-getx

Is it possible, in Dart, to have generic methods in non-generic class, like in Java?

I use [Getx](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx) for state management, DI & routing, but this question is not specific to Getx or Flutter.

I've `AuthService` which deals with authentication and sets logged in user, like `Rxn<AppUser>`. I've 3 types users:  `Customer extends AppUser`, `Seller extends AppUser` & `Admin extends AppUser`.

I want to change the user observable to something like this: `Rxn<? extends AppUser> currentUser = Rxn()`.

I tried below syntax, but doesn't work.

```
class AuthService extends GetxService {
  T Rxn<T extends AppUser> currentUser = Rxn();
  ...
}
```

**Direct answer to my question:**
Dart supports inheritance in generic types too (unlike in Java). So, `Rxn<AppUser> currentUser = Rxn<Patient>()` is possible in Dart. I don't need wildcard or any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have generic methods.  You'd declare them the same way as you'd declare generic functions:

```dart
class Foo {
  String key;

  Foo(this.key);

  Map<String, T> f<T>(T value) => <String, T>{key: value};
}
```

However, it doesn't make sense to have generic fields.  A field represents a data member; what data would be stored and where when the type isn't known yet?  Would you store a potentially infinite number of data members for every possible value of `T`?

Comment: Generic field do have benefit. With something like `Rx<? extends AppUser> currentUser` I can enforce the assignment to be of only sub types, like `currentUser = Rx<Admin>()`, but not `currentUser = Rx<Foo>()`

Comment: Does Dart support `Rx<? extends AppUser> currentUser` or `Rx<T extends AppUser> currentUser` or similar syntax for fields/properties? Thanks

Comment: @manikanta Why wouldn't you just declare your field as `Rx<AppUser> currentUser` then?  Or why not make the class generic?  You also could make the member private and provide generic functions to get and set it (and cast to and from a base type).

Comment: Ohhhh, Dart supports inheritance in generics too!!! `Rxn<AppUser> t = Rxn<Patient>()` is valid in Dart. Just checked the syntax. I'm from Java background, and Java doesn't allow this.

Comment: I could make class a generic one, but in this specific scenario, I will only have one `AuthService` for all types of user. So having user type as generic in `AuthService` doesn't make sense here. Thanks